# getJSON to string then loop through string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code which is included in a `keypress` function:

```
$.getJSON('dimensions.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        $('#div1').append(index);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to first get the JSON string, save it in a variable and then run the `each()`. I want to basically separate the `each()` to be unlinked to the `getJSON()` function because I don't want it to fetch the json file for every keypress.

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var JSONstr = $.getJSON('dimensions.json');
$.each(JSONstr, function(index) {
    $('#div1').append(index);
});
```

Comment: Have you compared console.log(data) and console.log(JSONstr) ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  (You can't, is why I ask.)

Comment: @Pointy - The first code snippet is included within a 'keypress' function, so at the moment every time a key is pressed, my script is fetching the json file. I wanted to fetch it once to a var and then run the keypress function on the var.

Comment: The problem is that you can't be sure that the variable's value is available until the callback to the `$.getJSON`.  What you could do is defer binding of the "keypress" handler to inside that callback as well.

Comment: @hoverhand please edit your question with this extra information, it's not obvious what you mean at first. (I'm editing my answer)

Comment: @Pointy - isn't it unusual that you can't save the json string and parse it later on? Can't this be solved by using jqXHR?

Comment: @hoverhand It's not that you can't save it for later use, it's that you don't have the value yet to save.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski can you elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: If you don't want to make a request for the JSON, then what are you doing...appending the results to the body every time a key is pressed?

Comment: @gengkev I'm building a small 'suggest' script that for every keypress runs through the JSON and appends the relevant results to the div.

Comment: BTW if you need the JSON every time, you can just as well assign it to a variable in the code of the page on output, instead of bothering with ajax.

Comment: @hoverhand `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. It starts the request, sets the callback to be called when the request has completed, and returns immediately. This means the callback is almost always called later and the results aren't available until then, usually after the rest of your code has already finished executing. But, the callback can be used to set the results to a variable in an outer scope, making it available to the `$.each` without another `$.getJSON` request (see [a sad dude's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774111/15031) for an example).

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you do $.each in the callback. The callback is executed by *some other callback* after there result is received, while $.getJSON returns *immediately* without waiting for the result (since there is no blocking in JavaScript by design).

Therefore the code in your second example can never work: the $.each begins before any result is received from the web server, probably even before the request is sent. Whatever the return value of $.getJSON is, it *can't*, by the design of JavaScript, be the result of AJAX request.

**UPD:** Saw your comment, now I understand what you wanted to do. Here's a simple example of how to do this:

```
function ActualHandler(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        $('#div1').append(index);
    });
}

function KeypressHandler() {
    if (window.my_data) { // If we have the data saved, work with it
        ActualHandler(window.my_data);
    }
    else { // Otherwise, send the request, wait for the answer, then do something
        $.getJSON('dimensions.json', function(data) {
             window.my_data = data; // Save the data
             ActualHandler(data); // And *then* work on it
        });
    }
}
```

Here, the ActualHandler is not launched before the data is received, and once that happens, all subsequent clicks will be handled immediately.

The downside in this particular case is that if user clicks again while the first request is running, one more will be sent. But to fix that you would need to maintain some queue, which is kind of out of scope here.

Comment: He wants the $.each() to run outside of the $.getJSON() callback.

Comment: Maybe you could save the JSON data in a variable and then run HandleJSON with that variable onkeypress?

Comment: Exactly what my code does, no? Except for the first time, when the only alternatives to run it "outside" of callback is a) inside of setInterval callback b) not running it at all c) running it without any data. None of these look like a solution me.

Answer (score 0):

You fell into the asynchronous trap. Your `$.each()` function doesn't wait for your `$.getJSON()` call to get the data.  You can get around this by using the good 'ol `$.ajax()` function. Like this:

```
function processJSON(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        $('#div1').append(index);
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'dimensions.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: processJSON(data)
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't separate between the each and the file being fetched